# Is there a compact notation for indicating the reasons for an implication?

Tags: logic, notation

Is there a compact, commonly used notation for indicating the reasons for an implication? For example, suppose I have previously established or been given $P$, and can use it to show that $B$ follows from $A$ because of $P$. I'd like to be able to write something like

$$A \underset{P}\Rightarrow  B,$$

but feel like I'm making up notation that will not be understood. Is something like this common practice, and if so are there LaTeX conventions for generating it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the super useful `mathtools` package (for bunch of other stuff too!). Use it with `\xRightarrow[below]{above}`. There is also `extarrows` package with similar usage `\xlongequal[below]{above}`.

My humble advice is not to exploit this, rather keep the text at max `from (2) and (5)` or `via Fubini Thm.` or something similar to draw attention to known results, previous relations, elsewhere in the text.

Answer (score 8):

When people write mathematics on a blackboard, they have many idiosyncratic ways of abbreviating arguments to save space. But when we write mathematics in print, we typically use prose. So there is no common way in LaTeX to do what you ask, because we generally just explain the argument in words.

Comment: Exactly! Why do some people tend to obsess about notation? The main goal is to communicate the mathematics and, yes, a good notation that everyone understands is great for that, but not obscure, complicated notation.

Comment: I've seen people use $\because$ `\because` and $\therefore$ `\therefore` on blackboards. I find this utterly confusing because I can't remember which one is which. $p \mid a \implies p^2 \mid a \because a \text{ is a } \Box$... This would give $P \therefore A \implies B$ or $A \implies B \because P$.

Comment: @lhf: Actually, my purpose was not to obscure or merely save space, but to take advantage of compact notation to make it easier to grasp the structure of an argument without having to refer to surrounding text. One of the things I find hardest as a (slightly dyslexic) beginner is assessing the precise meaning of natural language in the context of mathematical arguments, and (to me, at least) a well-defined notation helps with that.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius, I didn't mean you personally (and hence the comment to this answer and not your question). No offense meant.

Comment: @lhf: Yes, sorry, that came off wrong. A further note: Another goal is to have a way of putting $P$ in as close a proximity as possible to the step that uses it. I often find, for example, that when I see "from P" followed by some notation, it is not always clear precisely what elements of the notation are related through $P$.

Comment: @t.b. when I was half my current age, the $\because$ and $\therefore$ notations were part of the secondary school curriculum in Taiwan. On the other hand, the $\implies$ sign was not used.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enphasize that you are using P, together with A, to deduce B

you could write

P & A ⟹ B

that is: if P and A then B

This is standard logic notation and it draws attention to P.
It might also come useful if you or your readers want to use some proof-assistant or automatic-theorem-prover

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is done in type theory. The [HoTT book](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/) has some nice explanations that are digestible for mathematicians.

Basically, given that [propositions are types](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/propositions+as+types), then the propositions $A$ and $B$ can both be interpreted as types. Evidence for $A$ is a term of type $A$, written $a:A$, and similarly evidence for $B$ is a term of type $B$.

A proof $p$ of the proposition $A \implies B$ is an argument that converts evidence for $A$ into evidence for $B$. But thinking type-theoretically, this is just a function (i.e. a term of function type). Thus, a type theorist would write
$$p: A \to B.$$

If you want to use the classical double arrow for implication, then I would suggest writing
$$p: A \Rightarrow B.$$

Now, say that you have a proof $a:A$ and you have a proof $p:A \to B$, then you just use function application to get a proof of $B$, namely $$p(a):B.$$